# What is wrong in my gradle file?

Tags: android

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.oumnia.advalio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    //compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    //compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
    //compile project(':httpmime-4.3.1')
    //compile project(':httpcore-4.2.3')
    //compile project(':httpclient-4.5.2')
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
    compile project(':httpmime-4.3.1')
    compile project(':httpcore-4.2.3')

}
```

i get this error  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/HttpMessage.class

Can someone please tell me what's wrong in my gradle file?

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.oumnia.advalio"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    //compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    //compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
    compile project(':httpmime-4.3.1')
    compile project(':httpcore-4.2.3')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Apache lib if you are trying to compile using API 23. Or add this line inside Android tag

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

Comment: u mean i should replace compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

Comment: Change compile SDK version to 21 and buid

Comment: u mean i should replace this line                                                              compile'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'                                                                                            by this one compile  'org.apache.http.legacy'   ??

Comment: No..change line no.3 in your build.gradle and change value to 21 or something or instead simply add useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' in your build.gradle.

Comment: but my dependecies depend to version 23??                                                                         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

Comment: U simply add useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' in ur build.gradle.  any where inside Android{} reply if that worked

Comment: i think this line fixed the prob bu i have new error                                                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.util.Args
                                                                                at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.

Comment: sorry. but still the same prob    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.util.Args
                                                                              at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.<init>(AbstractContentBody.java:48)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:96)
                                                                              at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)

Comment: U uncomment those commented lines from build.gradle only 4.3 line

Comment: i uncomment thistwo lines compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3" and i get this error Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.class

Comment: And comment the last two lines and uncomment the two as u did before

Comment: same error  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.class

Comment: compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
   // compile project(':httpmime-4.3.1')
   // compile project(':httpcore-4.2.3')

Comment: Hope this may help u.reply if it helped

Comment: thank u for ur help but i still having the same prob i commented my copiles and use urs but nothing changed.

Comment: Can u copy the whole build.gradle file

Comment: OK got it...remove these two lines compile project(':httpmime-4.3.1')
    compile project(':httpcore-4.2.3')

Comment: sorry i don't have enough reputations